# Proving that a piecewise function $f(x,y,z)$ cannot be continuous at the origin

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

I am presented with the following problem.

> Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
>
> $$f(x,y,z)=
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{z}{x}+y & \text{if} \: x \neq 0, \\
> a & \text{if} \: x=0,
> \end{cases}$$
>
> where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is some fixed constant.
>
> Determine whether there exists a value of $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y,z)$ is continuous at the origin, justify your answer.

Here is my argument.

Consider the sequence $\vec{x}_n=\left( \frac2n,\frac1n,\frac1n \right) \in \mathbb{R}^3$. This means that $\left\{ \vec{x}_n \right\} \to (0,0,0)$ as $n \to \infty$. However, $f\left( \vec{x}_n \right)=\frac{1/n}{2/n}+1/n=1/2+1/n \to 1/2$ as $n \to \infty$.

If we consider $\vec{x}_n \Rightarrow a=1/2=\lim_{n \to \infty}f\left( \vec{x}_n \right)$. But now if we consider $\vec{y}_n=\left( \frac4n,\frac1n,\frac1n \right) \in \mathbb{R}^3$, we still have that $\left\{ \vec{y}_n \right\} \to (0,0,0)$ as $n \to \infty$, but $f\left( \vec{y}_n \right)=\frac{1/n}{4/n}+1/n=1/4+1/n \to 1/4 \neq a$ as $n \to \infty$.

Thus, $f$ cannot be made continuous for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Some verification/help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

In order $f$ to be continuous at origin
$\lim_{P\to 0}f(P)$ must exist and equal to $f(0) = a$

What you did is true but there is no need to use series or $x_n$s. You can just take the limit with 2 different approaches to origin and show they give different results.

i) Approach origin by choosing $P=(h,h,h)$ then $\lim_{h\to 0}f(h,h,h) = 1$

ii) Approach origin by choosing $P=(2h,h,h)$ then $\lim_{h\to 0}f(2h,h,h) = 1/2$

Thus limit does not exist.